# Merge conflicts during reword (git rebase -i)

Tags: git, rebase

It seems, I am lacking some understanding of git.

I am currently in the process of an extensive

```
git rebase -i --root
```

on origin/main(master), which is not a fork.

- Commits are not reordered
- There are several merge commits into main

My todo file contains only

- pick and
- reword,

as many commit messages must be changed to pass commit linting.

Why do I have to manually resolve such merge conflicts?

```
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in file1
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in file2
```

I would expect that changing commit messages should be possible independently of the changes in the code base.

Could one reason be past forced updates?

Comment: This question is lacking details. Did you have merge commits? Are you reordering commits? What kind of conflicts? Do you move/change the upstream?

Comment: @knittl Thank you, you are right. I added additional important information to the post.

Comment: Rebasing flattens the history, meaning that the merge commits are removed. If you had resolved merge conflicts, those will show up again. If you didn't, then the linearizing of the history might introduce new conflicts. You can try the rebase option to preserve merges

Comment: @knittl Thanks a lot. This is certainly the reason. I didn't know that this was  default behaviour. I will restart the rebase with --preserve-merges then.

Comment: I would rather use `git replace` and `git filter-repo` if I was rewriting all commit messages from the root. There is `git replace --edit` which lets you edit the message in an editor. That can be scripted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you did not use `--rebase-merges`, you are missing merges *with* changes (like conflict resolution)... and that is causing the current conflicts in the rebase. If you will only do a reword of a commit (and you won't change any files), you should try:

```
git rebase --rebase-merges -i --root
```

Then, everytime you hit a conflict (like in some merge commits where you faced them originally), you can do this to reuse the original conflict resolution without having to do any additional work:

```
git restore --staged --worktree --source=REBASE_HEAD -- .
git rebase --continue
```

Until the rebase is finished. *And*, in case it is not obvious, you must not introduce any new changes in the files while you are doing the rebase because using this would remove those changes on later commits where there are conflicts.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. There is one aspect not 100% clear still: On hitting a merge commit using --rebase-merges, where does the information come from on how the conflict has been resolved in the past? I should have the FEATURE_HEAD of my feature branch and HEAD of my main before the merge. I suppose REBASE_HEAD means the commit created by git after merging the two histories in the past?

Comment: `REBASE_HEAD` is a special reference that points to the commit that is being _rebased/applied_ at the time... that is why using it in every commit where there is a conflict works..... _and_, of course, that is so because you did not introduce any changes in the contents of the files.... if you had done it, then the trick would not work.